# How to open a URI when the filename contains "?" and "=" characters?

Tags: url, browser

I have a file named `index.php?title=dogs` in my web directory, and I want to open it in a browser. What URL should I put in? When I put in `.../index.php?title=dogs`, it thinks that I'm looking for a file called `index.php`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex value for `?` in ASCII is 0x3f, so the URL encoded form is %3f and the value of `=` is 0x3d, so %3d, giving

```
.../index.php%3ftitle%3ddogs
```

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

N.B. you probably don't need to escape the `=` once you've escaped the `?`

But you should probably think about changing the file's name!

Answer (score 0):

The webserver assumes that everything after the ? is a parameter to the "index.php" file, what is called a **QueryString**, so it takes it out of the path and then passes it to the index.php file (depending on what webserver you have).
You could resolve the issue using custom settings on the webserver.. but personally I don't recommend it.

PS: I didn't know you could create files with a name like that!

Comment: don't change the webserver's settings, just escape the ? in the URI